# JAVA: If I have a global variable, why only in method it has value?

Tags: java

I don't understand this code:

```
public class UserIntroActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText userName;
    public String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_intro);

        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

                Intent intent = new Intent(UserIntroActivity.this,
                        EnterActivity.class);
                
                name = userName.getText().toString();
                
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

        Log.d("USER", name);
    }
    }
```

This is basic java question, so I am very sorry but I need explanation. If I "public String name;" set as global for this class, why value in method is not added to it. In method I get name, but when method is finisted name is deleting and I have **name = null**.

Comment: name will have a value only when btnGo is clicked, when Log.d is called this callback is not fired yet so it will have null.

Comment: I have problem to take text from EditText if I dont do that here I have exception :/ do you know how to evade it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.d("USER", name);
```

Is displayed before you click the button thus giving a null value.

`name` will be null until the button is clicked.

If you do this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_intro);
 userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            name = userName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("USER", name);
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserIntroActivity.this,
                    EnterActivity.class);



            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Then name wont be null because you take the text from the edittext without clicking the button first

Comment: If I do that I get exception :/ is it because it tries to take name before I enter it?

Comment: @MalaAiko edditted add the log d inside the onClick

Comment: And that is fine, but what I want to do next is to save it in SharedPreferences... So I would like to take name out of range of method >.< (And because of it I left Log.d out so I can test it...)

Comment: @MalaAiko go here to learn about sharedpreferences http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to log the name object inside the onClick() method? In this case, the name will be logged on each click.